# PyQt4: Unstable QTableWidget after adding a QLineEdit with a QCompleter

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I would like to have a table with one column that has auto-complete. I figured the best way to do this would be to use a QTableWidget and then instead of using the default QTableWidgetItem (which does not suport QCompleters) I would set the cell to a QLineEdit with the completer on it. However when I do this the cell box outlines are flickering and I get the following error: `QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread`

Here's a sample. Try adding a few rows (+ on the numpad), adding data to them and then quickly closing to get the error.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class DevTLog(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DevTLog, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Actions
        self.addItemAction = QtGui.QAction("Add row", self)
        self.addItemAction.setShortcut(QtCore.Qt.Key_Plus)

        # Menu
        menu = self.menuBar()

        menu_file = menu.addMenu("File")
        menu_file.addAction(self.addItemAction)

        # Table
        self.log = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.log.setColumnCount(3)
        self.log.setColumnWidth(0,150)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.log)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)

        # signals/slots
        self.addItemAction.triggered.connect(self.addItem)

    def addItem(self):

        nameItem = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        completer = QtGui.QCompleter()
        nameItem.setCompleter(completer)

        row = self.log.rowCount()
        self.log.insertRow(row)
        self.log.setItem(row, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())
        self.log.setCellWidget(row, 1, nameItem)
        self.log.setItem(row, 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = DevTLog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Change `completer = QtGui.QCompleter()` to `completer = QtGui.QCompleter(self)`

Comment: Hah, got me again! I'll admit this is my first time learning about QCompleter...

Comment: I think QCompleter uses a timer, and what I suspect happens is that the garbage collector is removing it from the context, which generates that error since the timer would be in another context.